# Loading a cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have saved a Matlab file in the computer memory called `data.mat`. The file is structured as a cell with dimension `13x1`. To save the file, I have used the command `save('data.mat', 'data')`.

Now, I want to load the file and transform it.

This is what I am doing at the moment

```
%Load data
load data
%Transform data
for n=1:13
    data{n}(:,1)=rand(10,1); %replace first column
end
```

However, I get as a warning message on the Matlab script:
"***The variable data appears to change size at every loop iteration. Consider preallocating for speed***".

In short, the script does not recognise that I have loaded a cell.

How can I fix this? It is not an error message and Matlab does OK when running the code. I just want to remove the warning thing.

Comment: What you have in the data before saving? Maybe you can be increasing the size of each matrix in the cell.

Comment: @Guto It is not an error message and Matlab does OK when running the code. I just want to remove the warning thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this warning because the Editor has no way of knowing what format your variable `data` will have until it is loaded from the MAT file. Since `data` isn't defined, it likely assumes you are making it from scratch and issues the warning. If you're certain you aren't going to be growing your cell array (i.e. you will only ever modify existing cells), you can just suppress the warning by adding this as the first comment on that line:

```
%#ok<SAGROW>
```

Or by right clicking on the highlighted word `data` and selecting the options "Suppress.. On This Line", which will add the comment for you.

More information on this can be found in [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-code-for-errors-and-warnings.html).